# Adding column to a matrix

Tags: r

What is wrong here?

```
datMat <- matrix(runif(40,1,20),ncol=4)
datMat[,5]=rep(1,nrow(datMat))
```

Output:

```
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, , 5, value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)) : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Why cant I add new column?

Comment: `cbind(datMat,1)`

Comment: Re why, with matrices, you need to assign to existing indices, as the error said.

Comment: Matrices are not data frames.

Comment: `structure(c(datMat,rep(1,nrow(datMat))),.Dim=c(nrow(datMat),ncol(datMat)+1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to reference a column that doesn't exist in the matrix yet. You can add columns to a matrix by

`datMat = cbind(datMat,rep(1,nrow(datMat)))`

But this is inefficient. It is better to create a matrix fully with 0 or NA and then add entries later like:
`datMat = matrix(c(runif(40,1,20),rep(NA,10)),ncol=5,byrow=F)
datMat[,5] = rep(1,nrow(datMat))`